# Spring authorization Sever custom UserDetails JSON deserialization issue

Tags: java, spring-security, jackson, objectmapper, spring-authorization-server

I am fighting against JSON deserialization for a while now by trying to migrate from Keycloak to Spring Authorization Server (I am still wonder if it's a good idea with all those issues). Anyway...

Firstly trying to get an access token using the code grant type, I had that exception when using a CustomUserDetails

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with com.company.user.CustomUserDetails and name of com.company.user.CustomUserDetails is not in the allowlist. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or by providing a Mixin. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4370 for details
```

I visited the link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4370 but nothing really helpful.

Based on the error message I defined this CustomUserDetailsMixin

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomUserDetailsSerializer.class)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class CustomUserDetailsMixin {
}
```

And the `CustomUserDetailsSerializer`:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<CustomUserDetails> {
    private static final TypeReference<Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority>> SIMPLE_GRANTED_AUTHORITY_SET = new TypeReference<>() {
    };

    @Override
    public CustomUserDetails deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jp);

        //there is an issue here :
        Set<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = mapper.convertValue(jsonNode.get("authorities"), SIMPLE_GRANTED_AUTHORITY_SET);
    }
}
```

And registered it here:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration {

    @Bean 
    public OAuth2AuthorizationService oAuth2AuthorizationService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService oAuth2AuthorizationService = new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
        JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper rowMapper = new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper(registeredClientRepository);
        ClassLoader classLoader = JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.class.getClassLoader();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModules(new CoreJackson2Module());
        objectMapper.registerModules(SecurityJackson2Modules.getModules(classLoader));
        objectMapper.registerModule(new OAuth2AuthorizationServerJackson2Module());

        //registering the mixin
        objectMapper.addMixIn(CustomUserDetails.class, CustomUserDetailsMixin.class);

        rowMapper.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        oAuth2AuthorizationService.setAuthorizationRowMapper(rowMapper);
        return oAuth2AuthorizationService;
    }

}
```

But now I have another error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve type id 'java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN' as a subtype of `java.util.Set<org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority>`: Not a subtype
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService$OAuth2AuthorizationRowMapper.parseMap(JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.java:467)
```

I took a look at the JSON saved in db by spring security and it looks like this:

```
{
  "@class": "java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap",
  "java.security.Principal": {
    "@class": "org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken",
    "authorities": [
      "java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList",
      [
        {
          "@class": "org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority",
          "authority": "ROLE_USER"
        }
      ]
    ],
   }
  ....
}
```

The question is how to solve that last error?

Comment: I am curious: why migrate from Keycloak to spring authorization-server? Doesn't the first have so many more features?

Comment: Smaller footprint, better customizable if you already have a spring stack running, less stuff you may not need -  I do use spring-auth-server too instead of that keycloak one which I just don't need.

Comment: @ch4mp Torsten Krah summerized the reasons I am migrating to Spring Authorization Server, I want to customize as I wish my authorization server. Also Keycloak does not provide an opaque token and for some clients I need that kind of tokens.

Comment: You can introspect JWTs if that's the matter (and Keycloak exposes an introspection endpoint). For the "better customizable", I'd be curious of what you couldn't do with Keycloak. "Smaller footprint", maybe, at the cost of clients and user management UI (and so much configuration burdon)...

Comment: @ch4mp I simply don't want a JWT format even if I can introspect it, I need another format which we can't see its claims. Also my apps are deployed in the cloud and with Keycloak I have to provide a dedicated database and have to manage a full application. Migrating to Spring Authorization Server, with one dependency I can reuse one of the database of one application (and so limiting the number of required connexions). I don't really need the UI provided by Keycloak which prevent us to really understand what happens behind the scene

Comment: Can't opaque token claims be seen on introspection endpoint? Or is it hidden behind a firewall as well as user endpoint? If the aim is protecting tokens content from the "outside", why not using the [BFF pattern](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) where the tokens don't leave your servers at all? Regarding DB, why couldn't you use one of your applications DB with Keycloak?

Comment: But I guess, all those are tradeoffs and partly opinions and I thank you for sharing yours. I think the most important grief I have against spring authorization server is it mobilises a lot of Spring security team energy, leaving much less for the security framework...

Comment: @ch4mp I can use the db of one application but that means increasing the number of db connections, what I want is to reduce the number of apps to manage and have fine grained control about users management. I  agree with you about the complexity of Spring Security, sometimes I ask myself what am I doing since it's not really trivial to understand what's going above all when we define multiple SecurityFilterChain. 
Thank you for the link on BFF pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by manually extracting the roles from the JSON, it's not the better way to go but I can go ahead.

**EDIT**

A better altenative is to avoid using ImmutableCollection or provide a dedicated mixin.
I changed all codes that created an ImmutableCollection like `...stream().toList()` to `...stream().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 0):

the "java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList" type info in the json is not compatible with your
SIMPLE_GRANTED_AUTHORITY_SET type reference, so there is a easy way to prcess.

use the type reference that already registed in CoreJackson2Module, and then convert it to the type actually required.

```
        TypeReference<List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>> listType = new TypeReference<>() {
        };

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authoritiesList = mapper.convertValue(jsonNode.get("authorities"), listType);
        Set<? extends SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = authoritiesList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thank you but I already tried that solution without success

Comment: I solved the issue by manually extracting the roles from the json

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service implemented "UserDetailsManager" instead of "UserDetails".
You need override "loadUserByUsername" method:

```java
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<SecurityUser> optional = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (!optional.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + username + "' not found");
        }
        SecurityUser user = optional.get();
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        user.getAuthorities().forEach(auth -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth.getAuthority())));

        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), !user.isDisable(), !user.isExpired(),
                !user.isCredentialsExpired(), !user.isLocked(), authorities);
    }
```

SecurityUser is my custom Entity and User in return is "org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User"

Here is some of my custom Entity:

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "users")
public class SecurityUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NonNull
    private String password;

    @Singular
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_authorities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authorities_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Authority> authorities;

    @Builder.Default
    private boolean expired = false;
    @Builder.Default
    private boolean locked = false;
    @Builder.Default
    private boolean credentialsExpired = false;
    @Builder.Default
    private boolean disable = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how your answer is answering my question. The issue comes from JSON deserialization and your answer has nothing related to it.

Comment: @akuma8 this avoid use customUserDetailsMixin. I had the same problem and using UserDetailManager was the short way